# Only element boundaries can be connected in jointjs？

Tags: jointjs

I just want to make my element boundary "magnet=true", and the internal is not a crosshair cursor but a move cursor, how to achieve?

Comment: please add more details to the question, it is not clear what you're asking

Comment: my element is a rect with image, and I want the sides of rect can be connected.But when I  add "magnet=true" to my rect and the cursor into the internal,the cursor will  be a crosshair rather than a move cursor that I wanted.How can I do?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my element definition as follows:

```
markup :
...
<rect class="body"/>
<rect class="icon-box"/>
<path class="ele-icon"/>
...
```

---

```
attrs:

...
'.body':{magnet:true,width:50,height:50}
'.icon-box':{
    width:48,
    height:48, 
    'x-alignment': 'middle',
    'y-alignment': 'middle',
    'ref-x': .5,
    'ref-y': .5,
    ref: '.body',
    fill:'white'
}
...
```

I added a rect as a box of icon,so that only the outside of icon-box can connect.

**I will be very grateful if you have a better way!!!**